# sys.exc_info or sys.last_*?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, sys, traceback

Should I prefer [`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) over [`sys.last_value`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.last_type) and friends (`sys.last_type`, `sys.last_traceback`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of `sys.last_value` and friends:

> Their intended use is to allow an interactive user to import a debugger module and engage in post-mortem debugging without having to re-execute the command that caused the error.

So, if you are in an interpreter doing debugging I suggest using `sys.last_value`,  but in a script I suggest you to use `sys.exc_info()`.